# Appending data to an object JSON field using json_encode/decode transforms my array into an int Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, database

So I have a class "File" that has a field "file_history" in JSON, and in my CRUD operations on Laravel I'd like to append some JSON values to this field, for instance, when I'm creating my File object in my database, I first have `{"created_at": "2022-07-18"}` in my file_history field.
And then if I update my object I would now have:

```
{
    "created_at": "2022-07-18"
},
{
    "updated_at": "2022-07-08"
}
```

So I first thought about transforming my initial JSON values from my previous CRUD operations on the object into an array, append the new JSON values to this array, and then encode my array again into JSON. This is the code I wrote:

```
public function update(Request $request, String $uuid)
{
    $file = File::find($uuid);

    $json_data = array(
        "updated_at" => Carbon::now()
    );

    $file_history = json_decode($file->file_history, true);
    $file_history = array_push($file_history, $json_data);

    $file->file_history = json_encode($file_history);

    $file->update($request->all());
    return $file;
}
```

But using that code, I now have "2" in my database in my file_history field... I don't have JSON or anything else, just this 2 even if my field is categorized as JSON. Any idea why and how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: hi. what is in your code... you are doing stuff with arrays and file_history etc, but at the end you are updating with ->update($request->all()). code is not using encoded array to update. can you clarify this?

Comment: I put the $file->update($request->all) now for later when I'll add the possibility to update for example the name of my file which is another field in my database, I'll do that using a Request.. But yes, indeed I'm not using it right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have "2" in your database, because [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function returns the new number of elements in the array.
So your code shoud be like this:

```
$file_history = json_decode($file->file_history, true);
array_push($file_history, $json_data);

$file->file_history = json_encode($file_history);
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But now  my file_history changes are wrapped in a "0": `{"0": {"updated_at": "2022-07-18"}, "created_at": "2022-07-18"}`
I guess it's because I passed it first through an array, but is there a way to remove that incrementing value?

Comment: check using array_merge solves your problem.